# can delegates called on instance methods?

Tags: c#, .net, delegates

Can a delegate be called only on static methods.  I ran below code and got error as Method name expected at lines

> NuOp nuopAdd = new NuOp   (x.Addition(324324, 4324324));
>
> NuOp nuopMultiply = new NuOp(x.Multiplication(4324, 24234));

```
namespace DelegateEtAl
{
    public delegate double NuOp(double a, double b);

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Mop x = new Mop();
            NuOp nuopAdd = new NuOp   (x.Addition(324324, 4324324));
            NuOp nuopMultiply = new NuOp(x.Multiplication(4324, 24234));

            Console.Out.WriteLine(nuopAdd);
            Console.Out.WriteLine(nuopMultiply);
        }
    }

    public class Mop
    {
        public double Addition(double opA, double opB)
        {
            return opA + opB;
        }

        public double Multiplication(double opA, double opB)
        {
            return opA + opB;
        }
    }
}
```

When googled all the examples i found were dealing with only static methods.  but the below link states

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288459(v=vs.71).aspx

> For static methods, a delegate object encapsulates the method to be
> called. For instance methods, a delegate object encapsulates both an
> instance and a method on the instance.

Thanks.

Comment: Well your problem there is that you are instantiating a delegate **and** attempting to pass in parameters at the same time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call a delegate in either a static or not static method. There isn't any such a restriction. However, you have to do it as below:

```
NuOp nuopAdd = x.Addition;
NuOp nuopMultiply = x.Multiplication;

Console.Out.WriteLine(nuopAdd(324324, 4324324));
Console.Out.WriteLine(nuopMultiply(4324, 24234));
```

The problem with the way you used your delegates is the fact that you didn't initialized them correctly. This is clear if you read the definition of a delegate [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/):

> A delegate is a type **that represents references to methods** with a
>   particular parameter list and return type. When you instantiate a
>   delegate, you can associate its instance with any method with a
>   compatible signature and return type. You can invoke (or call) the
>   method through the delegate instance.

For further info in how we use a delegate please have a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/using-delegates).

In a few words, the delegate `NuOp` can point to any method, which takes two parameters of type double and return a double. In order you instatiate you delegate `NuOp` you just jave to assign the signature of such a method in `NuOp` like above.

Comment: @luckyluke you are welcome ! I am glad that I helped :)